# Create AlertDialog with elements generated at runtime

Tags: android, dynamic, android-alertdialog

I have found the following document at the Android dev site, which works for creating an AlertDialog with hard-coded elements : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList .

That works fine if you can hard-code them. However, in my application, I need to generate the items at runtime (prior to the generation, I don't even know the length of the items list), when the Dialog is requested for the first time.

How can I use a list generated at runtime, instead of the `final CharSequence[]` used in the example for the items in the AlertDialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Variable needs to be `final` only if you access it from within an inner class (OnClickListener in this case). Do you need to access the item list within an inner class?
2. `final` only means that reference must not change (= variable always points to same object). It says nothing how object is created. You can easily do:

   ```
   List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
   strings.add("Red");
   strings.add("Green");
   strings.add("Blue");

   final CharSequence[] items = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
   ```

Comment: I see, I'm a beginner in Java used to C++ so I didn't really know what `final` means. Thanks for clearing that up, this works perfectly.

Comment: my code predictions are totally  reduce ... such a usu full code thank you @Peter knego